# JQuery remove() not working with a two word id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button `<button onclick="takedown()"> take down </button>` that creates a H1 and button with the id of the text in my text field and h1 at the end for the h1 and button at the end for the button the button has a onclick `onclick="delete()"`. This is that function

```
    function takedown(){

note = document.getElementById("noteinput").value;

idh1 = note + "h1";
idbutton = note + "button";
idcenter = note + "center";

$('<center id="' + idcenter + '"> <h1 id="' + idh1 + '">' + note + '</h1> <button id="'+ idbutton +'" onclick="deletenote()"> Delete </button> </center>').appendTo("body");


}
```

For the delete function the remove() works only if the id of the button and the h1 is one word.

```
function deletenote(){
    // First setting
    var idbuttondelete = event.target.id;
    var idh1delete = idbuttondelete.replace("button", "h1");
    // Removing the button, h1,center
     $('#' + idbuttondelete).remove();
     $('#' + idh1delete).remove();

}
```

Does anybody know whats wrong or how to use JQuery to delete something if it has a two word id.

Comment: id's can't contain spaces...

Comment: @KevinB Is there a way the remove to spaces from the id

Comment: well of course there is. don't set the id to a string that has a space in it to begin with.

Comment: If that's out of your control, you'll have to find some other way to select the element (such as the attribute equals selector) then simply change the id property.

Comment: @KevinB The id of the h1 and button is set the text in a textfield so if the user puts in two word how do I remove the space from the id of the h1 and button

Comment: remove the space from the two words, or tell the user they can't do that.

Comment: setting ID from user input is not sensible. Very easy to have duplicates. Why do you need dynamic ID in first place? Lots of ways to traverse DOm without needing an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your replace in the delete function will fail if the user enters the word "button", "center", or "h1" as the javascript replace in the delete will only work on the first instance.  To prevent the user from having spaces try the below with the delete function you have:

```
function takedown(){
    var note = document.getElementById("noteinput").value;

    var idh1 = "h1" + note.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    var idbutton = "button" + note.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    var idcenter = "center" + note.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    //the above 3 variables will use _ instead of space

    $('<center id="' + idcenter + '"> <h1 id="' + idh1 + '">' + note + '</h1> <button id="'+ idbutton +'" onclick="deletenote()"> Delete </button> </center>').appendTo("body");
}
```

If you do not have control over the ID's and need to do this for a lot of objects you can change them all at once (buttons in this case)

```
$('button').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    $(this).attr('id', id);
});
```

And then you can reference all the buttons by ID using a _ instead of space.  Otherwise do as others suggested and use a selector other than ID

Answer (score 2):

This will not behave as expected because ID attribute values cannot contain spaces. Replace the spaces with underscore or some other allowed character:

```
// don't forget VAR or you will have a global variable (bad)
var note = document.getElementById("noteinput").value.replace(/\s/g, '_');
```

[How string.replace() works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace)

Comment: This works but it sets the h1 text to no spaces as well is there a way to do this only to the id

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you could try this:

```
var note = $("#noteinput").val().replace(/\s/g, '_');

idcenter = note + "center";

$('<center id="' + idcenter + '"> <h1>' + note + '</h1> <button id="'+ idbutton +'" onclick="deletenote(idcenter)"> Delete </button> </center>').appendTo("body");
}

function deletenote(id){
     $('#' + id).remove();
}
```

You don't need to individually remove the child elements of your  tag. I would also recommend against using the center tag, go with a div and center the contents with CSS rather than using center.

I also refactored your function. It's much better to pass in your values and this way, the function is more resuable and testable

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers...spaces in ids is bad practice!
BUT if you really need "two words" in your ids, instead of the query selector `$`, you can use:- 
 
`document.getElementById("doesnt mind spaces").remove();`